Suddenly can't boot my Ubuntu Desktop 23.10 (laptop HP Victus15 fb0xxx)
I can't boot my Ubuntu Desktop 23.10 (laptop HP Victus15 fb0xxx)
ACPI BIOS error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.28.EC0], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230331/dswload2-162)

ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20230331/psobject-220)


I noticed one more error:


Is there something more I need to add here?

Hope now it's ok

it hasn't worked for me
